# why is there an error in calling and checking the conditions of the array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        int [] testArray = new int [10];

        for(int k = 0; k<testArray.length; k++){

            testArray[k] = k + 1;
        }

        sum(testArray);

        for(int m = 0; m<testArray.length; m ++ ){

            if(testArray[m] == 7) {
                increaseByn(testArray, 3);
                sum(testArray);
                break;
            }
            else {
                increaseByn(testArray, 5);
                sum(testArray);
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    public static int sum(int [] nums){

        int sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++){

            System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");
            sum = sum + nums[i];
        }

        System.out.println("\n" + "Sum: " + sum);
        return sum;

    }

    public static int increaseByn(int [] nums, int n){

        int sum2 = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j<nums.length; j++){

            nums[j] = nums[j] + n;
            sum2 = sum2 + nums[j];
        }

        return sum2;
    }

}

// End of program
```

I would like to print the sum of the element in an array and also add 3 to each element if the previous array has 7, and add 5 to each element of the previous array otherwise.

I have two questions:

1.) How do I return the sum while calling the method sum?

2.) I want to check if the array has the above-listed numbers. Therefore, I wrote a for a loop. However, the for loop does not check both the conditions

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with *Sum of an element in an array*? The way your for loop is currently set up, it will exit after 1 element (do to the `break` statement being executed in the `else` branch (considering `testArray[0]` will always be `1`). If you want to increase all elements with 5 or 3, consider just multiplying the length of the array with 5 or 3 (it will be the same outcome). If you want to visualize your sum, either `System.out.println` it, or do something usefull with the result (for now you only execute the sum, but you don't capture it in a variable)

Comment: Any chance you can give a sample of an input and a sample of an output you are expecting? Maybe explaining a bit better what you want to do?

Comment: `sum(testArray); break;` appears in both the if and the else, so it can be replaced by a single occurrence after the if else statements.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, those `breaks` shouldn't be there, as they **stop the loop after the first iteration**:

```
    for(int m = 0; m<testArray.length; m ++ ){

        if(testArray[m] == 7) {
            increaseByn(testArray, 3);
            sum(testArray);
          //  break;
        }
        else {
            increaseByn(testArray, 5);
            sum(testArray);
        //    break;
        }
    }
```

Most surely the process increases 5 and just stops.

And in order to return the sum, you are already returning it (but doing nothing with it, as it is not referenced). You could save it into a new var:

```
  int mySum = sum(testArray);
  //do something with mySum
```

But then I'd delete those system outs into the sum function, if you don't want to saturate/duplicate the output:

```
public static int sum(int [] nums){

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++){

        //System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");
        sum = sum + nums[i];
    }

    //System.out.println("\n" + "Sum: " + sum);

    //return it and show it out of the function scope
    return sum;

}
```

Comment: You could argue that constantly doing the sum throughout the for loop isn't such a good idea either ;)

Comment: I do like your explanations, I think you made it a lot more clear to the OP what is stopping the program from executing as expected by the OP, just the constant `sum()` inside the for loop should be removed (imagine an array of 1000 elements)

Comment: Totally agreed @Icepickle, although didn't comment it because I don't know the logic/requirements of the OP. Good point anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could set a boolean flag to true if a `7` is found in the array and only increase each array element by 5 if it is not found at the end of the loop. Your current code will increment each element by 5 and break the loop if the first element is not 7.

After getting the sum once, you can easily calculate the new sum after incrementing by adding the number of elements by the increment and adding that to the original sum.

```
int sum = sum(testArray);
int currSum = 0;
boolean foundSeven = false;
for(int m = 0; m<testArray.length; m ++ ){
  if(testArray[m] == 7) {
      increaseByn(testArray, 3);
      foundSeven = true;
      currSum = sum + testArray.length * 3;
      break;
  }
}
if(!foundSeven){
    increaseByn(testArray, 5);
    currSum = sum + testArray.length * 5;
}
//currSum now has the sum of the updated array
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to do a `sum(testArray)` after either increase? (So after the `!foundSeven` `if` block)?

Comment: I would like to upvote, but iterating an array 3 times to find a sum kinda stops me (true, if it has a 7 and it's not the last element, it's 2.x times, but still, it simply doesn't feel efficient)

Comment: @Icepickle Thanks for the reminder. I've updated it again.

Comment: it doesn't make a difference as -> `sum()` iterates once, `increaseByn()` iterates once, and the `for` loop iterates once (when no 7 is there) :) (I don't think you need `increaseByn` if you multiply)

Answer (score 0):

I would really caution against looping the same array so often, why not capture if a 7 is in the array, create your sum while you iterate it once, and then multiply the array.length with 3 or 5 depending on having nr 7?

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String [] args){

        int [] testArray = new int [10];

        for(int k = 0; k<testArray.length; k++){

            testArray[k] = k + 1;
        }

        int sum = 0;
        boolean hasSeven = false;

        for(int m = 0; m<testArray.length; m ++ ){
            if(testArray[m] == 7) {
              hasSeven = true;
            }
            sum += testArray[m];
        }
        sum += (hasSeven ? 3 : 5) * testArray.length;
        System.out.println( sum );
    }
}
```